# Getting data from AsyncTask for widget

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I'm downloading some JSON weather data (City name and temperature) from internet with AsyncTask, I have also a widget which needs that downloaded information , widget updates every 30 minutes, I was able to transfer city name with `SharedPreferences` and static variables . so on every update it gets data. city information doesn't change so often as temperature. so how can I display temperature information from `AsyncTask` even when app isn't running and wasn't opened in last 30 minutes? 
should I set another `AsyncTask` in `WidgetProvider`? or there is a easier way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use any persistence tool you need to save the information and have the widget use that information independently.

For example save all the information to a file and simply have the widget know the file name, or a database...

static variables would be a bad idea in this case.

Comment: but if user haven't opened app , so Async task isn't executed how can widget download data?

Comment: @DTV for long-running operations and polls, you should use a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) instead of an `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Just use IntentService for this situation. Trigger it by alarms every 5/15/30 mins and after fetching data update widget by yourself. As you mention, android have restriction in widget provider xml update time (minimal time is every 30 mins), but where is no restriction on updating by yourself. So in your IntentService fetch your data, and after that:

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);
int widgetIds[] = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context,
                WidgetClass.class));
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context, R.id.widget_layout);//configure here your remoteViews
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetIds, views);
```